# cannot insert breakpoint x in shared object library , (python using .so library from c++)

Tags: python, c++, debugging, gdb, pdb

I'm trying to analyze c++ which is made into a .so file using pybind11.
The .so file has python API so the main python program uses the python API and calls functions in the .so file. I use two debugger for python (pdb) and c++ (gdb).
When I set breakpoint in the gdb, I get this error :

```
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0xb41798
```

when I set breakpoint in c++, there is no complaint, but when the program resumes in python, I have this error message in c++ debug window. How can I solve this problem?

ADD : here is how I run the debuggers .
for pdb : `python3 -m pdb test.py` for gdb : `ddd /usr/loca/.../dlib...gnu.so 10498` where 10498 was the process id of the python program
I made the .so file (dlib c++ to .so file containing python API) like this :
`sudo python3 setup.py install --clean --set USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=1 --set DLIB_USE_CUDA=1 --set CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="--expt-relaxed-constexpr" --compiler-flags "-O0 -g"`
the setup.cfg file has

```
[build_ext]  
debug = 1
```

maybe a problem in the way I made the .so file in?

Comment: how do your execute the probram? `gdb -r python -m pdb ...` ?

Comment: @SzabolcsDombi for pdb : `python3 -m pdb test.py`  for gdb : ddd /usr/loca/.../dlib...gnu.so 10498` where 10498 was the process id of the python program. I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for gdb : `ddd /usr/loca/.../dlib...gnu.so 10498`

Your DDD invocation is incorrect: the process `10498` is *not* running your `dlib...gnu.so` binary, it is running `python3` binary with the `.so` loaded into it.

You need to invoke it like so: `ddd python3 10498`.